# Fabric (Twitter) plugin icon doesn't show in PyCharm 3.0. How to fix it?

Tags: intellij-idea, pycharm, twitter-fabric

### Fabric (Twitter) plugin icon doesn't show in PyCharm 3.0. How to fix it?

I have View -> Toolbar enabled, I've installed the plugin for Intellij (downloaded from the official Fabric page) and restarted the IDE. The icon doesn't appear anywhere.
Can anyone help me?